# How to allow full use of all available swap space, when a process is running inside a Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, node.js

I have written a test Node app which eats memory (in 100MB chunks). I am trying to get it to continue allocating memory beyond the physical memory limit of 8GB by using the swap space which is configured on the Ubuntu box it is running on (16GB).

This is working fine when running normally in Node, like this:

```
node --max-old-space-size=16384 ./memtest/memtest.js
```

When I run it inside a Docker container, it is being terminated at the limit of physical memory.

I have tried some Docker options to try and get it to use the swap space, but it's still getting killed at the same point.

```
docker run -m 8g --memory-swap -1 --memory-swappiness 100 ...

Amount allocated before container is killed: 3037.08 MB

# swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  16G 187M   -2

# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8148324     1022788     5538364         124     1587172     6813484
Swap:      16777212      191228    16585984
```

From the docs below it would appear that the default behaviour should be to allow unbounded use of memory + swap - as I am trying to achieve. However, I am not seeing this.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

I am seeking to understand the reason why the behaviour is different inside Docker and how to allow *full use of all available swap space* **when the process is running inside a Docker container**.

Comment: To start with the most basic: for your system `docker info` does not show the message *"WARNING: No swap limit support"* that the manual warns about,  right?

Comment: @HBruijn It does show this warning, however, my understanding of this is that "Swap limit support" is required not to use swap normally, but to *limit the use of swap space* (not what I want to do). Is "swap limit support" required just to use swap space?

Comment: @HBruijn I have added `cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1` to grub init, updated grub and rebooted, the warning from `docker info` is gone, but I get the same behaviour - swap space is not available to the process.